# При написании буквы , условие не выполняется.Как написать,чтобы при написании буквы выполнялось условие " Не число.Введите число еще раз"

Tags: python

Определить является ли число простым. Попросить пользователя ввести произвольное целочисленное число. Вывести «Число простое», если число является простым и «Число не просто» в остальных случаях. Если пользователь вводит не число, то сообщить ему об этом и попросить ввести число еще раз. Ограничение на вводимое число: 0 < x < 100 000 000

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если попробовать написать N yне число,а букву, условие должно сказать"Не число.Введите еще раз число". Выходит ошибка,а нужно чтобы это условие работало.

Answer (score 1):

проверку на 0 < число < 100 000 000 можешь сделать самостоятельно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете написать часть  которую надо самостоятельно,выходит ошибка.

Comment: Могу, но не буду. Это же не моё задание. И так уже половину написал.

Comment: Спасибо,Эникейщик.

Answer (score -2):

Оберните весь ваш код в функцию

```
def f():
 //Ваш код
```

Вам нужно отслеживать ошибку с помощью

```
try:
  f()
except:
  //Тут выводим ошибку о том что это не число
  f()
```

Comment: Спасибо, EmilYayv

Comment: @Striz Мой ответ решил вашу проблему?